# How to disable/hide an error in Flash Builder 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

When writing code sometimes those red error icons pop up on the left side. Most of the time they are on point, but sometimes they are wrong. How can I hide them. They annoy me too much.

Comment: It would be interesting to know which errors are being reported wrong, (error or just a warning?)

Comment: Write code without errors, then they will go away :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red ones are proper errors, I am concerned about that they should actually be "wrong". The yellow (or orange) ones are warnings which can be hidden by using proper AS3 syntax.

Rob

Comment: well I have an event handler function
private function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void
  {
   var map:Map = event.target;
} and it says "implicit coercion of a value with static type object to a possibly unrelated type com.google.maps:Map

Comment: That's an error that will prevent your code from compiling right. So you really have to fix it before you can even get your project running. In this case you'd have to cast the 'event.target' to Map like this: `var map:Map = Map(event.target);`

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to flash so I didn't know that. I even tried `var map:Map = event.target:Map;`

Answer (score 0):

By default when you save your code in process of editing Flash Builder performs rebuilding of your project and if you have some errors in file (unfinished lines for example) it shows them as red markers.

If you want to control build process manually you can go to the `Project` menu and deselect `Build Automatically`. Now you can invoke build process manually to show error markers when you want. Just go to the same `Project` menu and select `Build project`. You can even assign keyboard shortcut for this operation.

Hope this helps!